# Issue with Webfont/font-face in child theme

Tags: fonts

I've uploaded a free webfont to my child theme. It's placed in a folder labelled 'fonts'.
I can't for the life of me get it to link correctly and work.

This is the code I'm using in the child theme stylesheet

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GlacialIndifference';
  src: url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('http:/MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       font-weight: 400;
       font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'GlacialIndifference';
  src: url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('http://MYWEBSITEURL.com/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       font-weight: 700;
       font-style: normal;
}
```

I've also tried the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GlacialIndifference';
  src: url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       font-weight: 400;
       font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'GlacialIndifference';
  src: url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('.../fonts/GlacialIndifference-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       font-weight: 700;
       font-style: normal;
}
```

I feel like both of those snippets above should work so I'm at a loss as to what I should try next.
I copied the font path directly from cPanel.

Help would be appreciated!

Cheers,
Rob

Comment: Check `url('/wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/fonts/GlacialIndifference...` (I think `url('fonts/GlacialIndifference...` or `url('./fonts/GlacialIndifference...` should work too assuming you CSS is `wp-content/themes/atmosphere-child/style.css`).

Comment: I've tried all of these with no success. Weirdly however, when I copy the link to the font into the browser it downloads without issue.